# What is this bash code doing?

Tags: bash, libtool

Here is some code I found in a file called libtool in an open source project (that is not compiling on this system):

```
  case $arg in
  -*=*)
    optarg=`$echo "X$arg" | $Xsed -e 's/[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*=//'` ;;
  *) optarg= ;;
  esac
```

I get the case statement, but I'm not sure about the first `optarg=...` line.  What is it trying to get at?  For this test case, let:

```
CC="arm-elf-gcc"
arg="--tag=CC"
Xsed="/usr/bin/sed -e 1s/^X//"
```

Running this in OS X gets me:

```
../libtool: line 828: X--tag=CC: command not found
```

I think it might be trying to assign "arm-elf-gcc" to the variable optarg, but I'm not sure.  The software overall compiles properly in Ubuntu, but the libtool file looks very different.

Comment: You're missing a definition for `$echo`; in most GNU software this is the result of a search for an `echo` implementation that doesn't expand escape sequences.

Comment: @geekosaur Debugging, $echo is found to be empty.  Any idea what to do off-hand (get a new echo?)?

Comment: You could try setting it to `echo`.  Also, if you're using a `libtool` generated on another system (for example, Linux vs. OS X), you might need to run `libtoolize` to generate a `libtool` that works on your local system.

Answer (score 1):

For your example where `arg="--tag=CC"` is is trying to isolate the value `CC`

It does this by using a regular expression to remove `--tag=`. The sed command `s/A/B/` replaces anything that matches A with B. A is a regular expression that is looking for any combination of letters, numbers, underscores and dashes followed by an equals and B is empty. So when it sees `--tag=CC` the regular expression matches `--tag` replaces it with nothing so the value is simply `CC`.

Answer (score 1):

This is just handling command-line arguments of the form

```
`--option=value`
```

In normal getopts processing, if you specify `-o value`, the variable `optarg` is set to `value`; this code makes sure the same thing happens if you instead specify the long form above (which looks like one big option argument to getopts).